# Es correcto decir “tiene que sea...”

Tags: aspecto-gramatical

Oí desde un programa del radio lo siguiente:

> A: ...donde algunas montañas llegan alcanzar los tres mil metros de
>   altura.
>
> B: ¡Tres mil! **Tiene que sea** complicado, ¿no?

Oí como “tiene que sea...”. Pero, me parece que no es correcto en punto de gramática. ¿O sí es correcto?

---

He tenido entendido que “tener que” debe seguir con verbo “inf.” Pero,  el locutor habló como “sea” con el ultimo sonido como “á”. Sé que no hay palabra “seá”, entonces, deduje que ser “sea”.

Comment: Seguramente también dijeron _llegan **a** alcanzar_. ¿Qué programa es? ¿No hay manera de conseguir las transcripciones de lo que dicen?

Comment: @fedorqui no, no hay transcripciones. He oido muchas veces pero aún no he oido bien.

Comment: no es mejor "tiene que ser" ?

Comment: que canal lo transmitio? univision ? univision tiene el peor uso del español dentro de la televisión.

Comment: A mis oídos, me suena horrible. ¿Estás 100 % segura de que escuchaste lo que escribiste en negrita?

Comment: Estoy seguro que dijeron tiene que ***ser*** complicado

Answer (score 4):

Estoy bastante seguro de que es un error. Si realmente dice *Tiene que…*, entonces a continuación debe venir un verbo en infinitivo (como *ser*); no puede venir un verbo en modo subjuntivo (como *sea*), ni de hecho ninguna otra forma verbal.

Creo que escuchaste mal, o también puede ser que la persona que habla no pronuncie bien las palabras. Puede ser un error gramatical, pero no es probable, porque *tiene que…* + infinitivo es una construcción que usamos todo el tiempo.

Comment: Bueno, los idiomas se pueden retorcer mucho para buscar ejemplos de cualquier cosa: "lo que tiene que sea un 3000 es que es complicado", significando "lo que implica que sea un 3000...". Pero claro, con ese contexto, sin duda es el infinitivo "ser".

Comment: TL;DR: tiene que *ser* un error :)